# Evenly distribute males and females in list with LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have `Class1` like:

```
{ 
  string Name, 
  string Sex
}
```

And I have a `List<Class1>` with 100 items where 50 are Males and 50 are Females, how do I get 10 groups of 5Males and 5Females each with LINQ?

I already manage to get the list grouped in 10 groups but not distributed evenly by sex.

```
  var foo = My100List.Select((person, index) => new {person, index})
                       .GroupBy(x => x.index%10)
                       .Select(i => new Group
                            { 
                               Name= "Group" + i.Key, 
                               Persons= i.Select(y => y.person).ToList()
                            });
```

The code above don't distribute by sex.

Comment: Are the group sizes constants or are you looking for a general solution?

Comment: It looks like you're close. Maybe add another `.GroupBy(p => p.Sex)` before the `.Select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
int groupSize = 5;
var foo = My100List.GroupBy(x => x.Sex)
                   .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x, i) => new { Person = x, Group = i / groupSize}))
                   .GroupBy(x => x.Group)
                   .Select(g => new Group
                   {
                       Name = "Group" + g.Key,
                       Persons = g.Select(x => x.Person).ToList()
                   });
```

**EDIT**

Tested and confirmed. The above code works.

Comment: Should use : (int)(i / 5)

Comment: @jdweng `i` is already an `int`. The cast would be redundant.

Comment: Really? but i/5 isn't. 3/5 = 0.6.  You will get 0,0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8 and will not go into same group.  This happened to me 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @jdweng `5` is an integer literal. An `int` divided by an `int` returns an `int`, meaning truncation is implicit. If it had been `i / 5.0`, then you would have a point.

Comment: You posted untested code and didn't confirm I was correct.

Comment: @jdweng It's not a matter of testing. It's how the language works. The only reason it's untested is because I don't have an array of 100 people to work with. Post the code into Visual Studio yourself to see the "Cast is redundant" warning. For that matter, just do `int i = 5; int j = i / 2;` and see that the result is 2 and the compiler doesn't even bat an eye over it.

Comment: You are defining i as an integer.  When you do i/5, 5 is not an integer so you get a floating point number.

Comment: @jdweng [5 is an integer literal.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx) You are confusing it with 5.0 which is a `double` (Real) literal.

Comment: @jdweng in C# integer divided by integer results in integer

Comment: I don't like getting into discussions like this. The casting to integer is performed by the compiler and doesn't effect the execution. Twice int the past few weeks I've spent time debugging an issue where groupby didn't work because a cast was needed. It is just good programming practice to make source code easy to understand and debug.   Anything that reduces time spent on a programming is good practice.Different compilers and compilers options work different. Linq behaves different from other code. If you have to spend more than 2 seconds thinks, then just do it if it makes the code clearer.

Comment: @jdweng Except there is literally no ambiguity to discuss. `i` is defined by the `Select` method to be an `int`, and `5` is an `int` by definition. There is no compiler difference to be concerned about because it is a basic definition in the C# language specification. The cast is redundant. It would be like doing `(string)"value"`. I don't know what casting issues you were having before, but it is not necessary to do so here, and doing so "just to be safe" makes it more verbose than it needs to be. It's a precaution that is completely not necessary by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @jdweng Any C# compiler that compiles `5` to anything other than an integer value does not meet C# specifications on the most fundamental level and shouldn't be used anyway.

Comment: You are wasting my time.  I got all A's in college programming.  What did you get?

Comment: @jdweng A job as a programmer heading a team that included programming interns who wasted far too much of their time worrying about what grades they were getting in college and destroying their code with a bunch of dated conventions that their professor taught them was the best and only way to properly program. Not that any of that is at all relevant to whether or not `5` is an `int`, though.

Comment: @jdweng The only person wasting your time is you. When you get backed against a wall in an argument, you throw out your college grades as if that somehow validates your point? What kind of logic is that supposed to demonstrate? This isn't a debate because, in this matter, you are objectively wrong. Dividing two integer values results in another integer value. `5` is an integer value by definition. You have no leg to stand on here. Either accept that gracefully and add it to your knowledge pool like a respectable programmer or reject it and let your skills suffer as a result.

Comment: @jdweng If you are so sure about your position, though, I invite you to prove me wrong. Show me a single case in C# where the literal `5` is anything other than an `int`, or where the division of two `int`s produces a floating point value.

Comment: @jdweng Another experiment occurred to me, and I thought I would share it with you. Say you do have `float a = 3 / 5;`, then If 3/5 = 0.6 like you said, then `a` would have ended up being `0.6`. But instead, `a` is equal to `0` afterwards. This proves that values like `3` and `5` are of type `int`, as they perform integer division before assigning the result to a variable of type `float`. So I hope that your straight-A's expertise can shed some light on this bizarre phenomenon, since you clearly know better than me.

Comment: this solution worked for the given case, but assuming I will not always want 10 groups but any given number of groups I make it work by changing the division by '5' for the modulo of the number of groups and it worked just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Add `.OrderBy` for sex before the `.Select`

Tested and working:

```
var foo = My100List.OrderBy(p => p.Sex).Select((person, index) => new {person, index})
                   .GroupBy(x => x.index%10)
                   .Select(i => new Group
                        { 
                           Name= "Group" + i.Key, 
                           Persons= i.Select(y => y.person).ToList()
                        });
```